# Is there any way to get Azure status update only for some services and regions I am using?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to get Azure status update only for some services and regions I am using? For example, I am using Cloud Services in West US. When this service in West US is down, I want to get an alert for it. I don't care about other services and other regions.

Comment: On the dashboard for Azure Cloud Services, there's an option to "Configure Web End Point Monitoring". Which can call endpoints in your app & send you an email if something doesn't work correctly. I also use Pingdom and New Relic in my app. Whenever my app goes down e.g, like when there's an Azure outage. I have Pingdom text me.

Comment: Better testing your app than testing the Azure infrastructure. Application insights has great tools for monitoring availability and alerting you when your services are down and/or inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up alert notifications for your application, you'll get notified when any of the underlying services you're using are not functioning properly. An alert will ensure that **your** service is available and working.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-receive-alert-notifications/

If you get an alert about a service issue, that's when I would first take a look at the [Azure status dashboard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/), and then take a look at your application logs to troubleshoot.

Another trick is to create simple URL's in your application that do a quick service test. For example, let's say you're using blob storage in the west datacenter. You could set up a page that does a test write/read to ensure that service is working. This will give you a 100% accurate indication if there is a problem. Since the cloud is highly distributed, and services statuses don't update immediately, I find this method highly preferable.

You would then point your alert monitoring at URL's like this:

- http://yourapp.com/
- http://yourapp.com/blobtest
- http://yourapp.com/redistest

Comment: I prefer the alert notification option but when I try to create an Alert Rule I cannot see options to specify "Events". I don't know where I can set Alert Rules other than this.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/ - It's part of Application Insights. When you set that up, you have the ability to add ping tests.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Status website has the information your need for all Azure regions.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: I know this page. What I need is I want to get notifications (sms or emails) for the services and regions that I am using (eg. Cloud Services in West US) and ignore the rest.